# How to make an If statement to not copy if there is nothing to copy

Tags: excel, vba

I know the question sounds a little confusing but the problem I am having is I have a database of line items. I use a Macro to filter and copy over these items into certain sections. On one section I do not have any items in the database as of now (probably will in the future but not sure). I noticed this section that should have nothing copying over was copying over everything in the database. I ran the Macro step by step to see that it filtered correctly with nothing showing up in the database but for some reason it copies over every item in the database. I'm not sure why it does this but below is the code I am using. I assume there is an If statement I could put on the 'To select correct data to copy code to say if the database filters nothing then don't copy anything but I'm not sure how to do it. Any help is much appreciated

```
'To filter data
'Sheets("Database").Select
'Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="2500", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="All"
'Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Adder"
'Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("FL", "MF", "HF", "Furnace Eng", "Launder"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
'To select correct data to copy
'Dim I As Long
'I = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'Range("B2:B" & I).Copy
'To copy data
'Sheets("Quote Sheet").Select
'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy filtered data use this method (**Untested**). I am also using the 3rd autofilter example from your code above to demonstrate the use of `.Offset`

```
    Dim Dim copyFrom As Range

   '~~> I am assuming that the Headers are in Row 1
   '~~> Filter, offset(to exclude headers) and set the filtered range
    With .Range("A1")
        .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("FL", "MF", "HF", "Furnace Eng", "Launder"), _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
        Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
    End With

    If Not copyfrom Is Nothing Then
        copyfrom.Copy '<~~ Copy the range
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just check in your situation:

```
If Range("B1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count >1 Then
```